# How do I fix this Spring Boot entity relationship Error "creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Unable to map collection"?

Tags: spring, entity, relationship

I am trying to create a secure login and I'm doing this by assigning a user to a role which will determine what kind of access they can have. My code has no errors but when I try to run the server I get the following error (my server will not even start):

"Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to map collection com.model.User.roles"

This is my role class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

public Role() {
}

public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

This is part of my User class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "emailAddress"))
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;
//@NotBlank

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Subject> subject;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public Collection<Role> roles;
```

This is my POM file (I know it is all over the place):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>com.finalYearProject</groupId>
<artifactId>student-life</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- upgrade to thymeleaf version 3 -->
     <thymeleaf.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency> 


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

UPDATE
This is what I changed in the Role class to fix the problem:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_userId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

Comment: Could you please paste a whole stack trace that you get during server launch?

Comment: @Kamil I added the server error there, is that what you mean by stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference Column in the User entity is wrong.

You have defined:

```
private Long userId;
```

So the user table has a PK with the name user_id and the mapping must be:

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "users_roles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
```

public Collection roles;

Comment: Thank you so much Simon you are an absolute hero! You have made my day <3 This is what I added and it fixed the problem:

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_userId", referencedColumnName = "userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a collection of Users in the Role class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Collection<User> users;
```